# Typescript best practices : Interfaces versus Classes

Tags: class, oop, typescript, interface, ecmascript-6

I'm using TypeScript since two years. Newly, I read something [on the Angular 2 Style Guide](https://angular.io/styleguide#!#-a-href-03-03-style-03-03-a-) :

> Consider using a class instead of an interface.
>
> Why? A class alone is less code than a class-plus-interface.
>
> Why? A class can act as an interface (use implements instead of
>   extends).
>
> Why? An interface-class can be a provider lookup token in Angular
>   dependency injection.

Sometimes I have simple literral object and to describe them I'm using Interface because this does not transpile any code so less expensive than a class.

Am I right ?

Can you tell when use interface and when not ?

Thanks.

Comment: Additionally to the reasons the ng2 styleguide already gave you, you can look for example here, were I also answered this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40591413/interface-and-class-in-typescript/40595930#40595930

Comment: I allowed myself to modify the tags and the title, in order to gain visibility with the programmers TypeScript and JavaScript in general.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question. We could analyze pros and cons of interfaces vs classes, but that belongs at [software-engineering](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/), here on SO it becomes too opinion-based as we don't have the correct framework to discus non-functional qualities like this in a productive way.

Comment: The question lacks the context. If the question applies to Angular development, it should mention this explicitly. If it's not, then the quote from A2 style guide is misleading. A2 can take advantage of a class which it can't take of an interface. As of 'less expensive', tree shaking can prevent output from classes that are used only as interfaces.

Comment: Thanks all, you answered my question.